# Azure Service Fabric 5.1.150.9590 on-premise cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy an on-premise 5-node cluster using Azure Service Fabric V5.1.150.9590 on 5 Windows Server 2012 R2 VMs.

Using ClusterConfig.Unsecure.json as pattern, I get the following exception:

```
    Create Cluster failed with exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentExcept
    ion: Primary node type node count is not sufficient for reliability level Bronze; You have total primary node type nodes
    : 1; the required seed node count for this reliability level is 3.
       at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.DeployAnywhereSettingsValidator.ValidatNodeTypes()
       at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.DeployAnywhereSettingsValidator.Validate()
       at System.Fabric.JsonImpl.ManifestConverter.ConstructClusterManifestBuilder(String jsonClusterConfigPath)
       at System.Fabric.JsonImpl.ManifestConverter.System.Fabric.JsonWrapper.IManifestConverter.ConvertFromJsonToXml(String jsonClusterConfigPath)
       at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabric PackageSourcePath, Boolean rollbackOnFailure)
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: Primary node type node count is not sufficient for reliability level  Bronze; You have total primary node type nodes: 1; the required seed node count for this reliability level is 3.
       at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.DeployAnywhereSettingsValidator.ValidatNodeTypes()
       at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.DeployAnywhereSettingsValidator.Validate()
       at System.Fabric.JsonImpl.ManifestConverter.ConstructClusterManifestBuilder(String jsonClusterConfigPath)
       at System.Fabric.JsonImpl.ManifestConverter.System.Fabric.JsonWrapper.IManifestConverter.ConvertFromJsonToXml(String jsonClusterConfigPath)
       at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsync>d__0.MoveNext()<---
```

I am at my wit's end trying to make this work. Does anyone have a sample of ClusterConfig.json that works with Azure Service Fabric V5.1.150.9590?

Any links to documentation about ClusterConfig.json will also be helpful.

Comment: How many nodes in “nodes” section do you have in this JSON file?

Comment: @cassandrad I have 5 nodes defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issues a few days ago. I switched to the latest SF version 5.1.150.9590, but used an old clusterConfig.json, which did not contain the values for **reliabilityLevel** and **isPrimary**. But with the below config I managed to setup a cluster. Please note, that this is a three node cluster, with one **nodeType**, which is marked as primary. So all three nodes are primaries.

```
{
   "name":"SampleCluster",
   "clusterManifestVersion":"1.0.0",
   "apiVersion":"2015-01-01-alpha",
   "nodes":[
      {
         "nodeName":"vm1",
         "iPAddress":"10.0.10.12",
         "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
         "faultDomain":"fd:/dc1/fd1",
         "upgradeDomain":"UD0"
      },
      {
         "nodeName":"vm2",
         "iPAddress":"10.0.11.12",
         "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
         "faultDomain":"fd:/dc1/fd2",
         "upgradeDomain":"UD1"
      },
      {
         "nodeName":"vm3",
         "iPAddress":"10.0.12.12",
         "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
         "faultDomain":"fd:/dc1/fd3",
         "upgradeDomain":"UD2"
      }
   ],
   "diagnosticsFileShare": {
        "etlReadIntervalInMinutes": "5",
        "uploadIntervalInMinutes": "10",
        "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "7",
        "etwStoreConnectionString": "file:c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\FileshareETW",
        "crashDumpConnectionString": "file:c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\FileshareCrashDump",
        "perfCtrConnectionString": "file:c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\FilesharePerfCtr"
    },
   "properties":{
       "reliabilityLevel": "Bronze",
        "nodeTypes": [
          {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpoint": "19001",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20001",
                "endPort": "20031"
            },
            "ephemeralPorts": {
                "startPort": "20032",
                "endPort": "20062"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
          }
      ],
      "fabricSettings": [
        {
          "name": "Setup",
          "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "FabricDataRoot",
                "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF"
            },
            {
                "name": "FabricLogRoot",
                "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF\\Log"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

**[Disclaimer]** To be precise: With the above config I managed to solve the particular error. However I am still with some other issues, which seem not related to this problem: [Error creating an on-premise multi-machine Service Fabric Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979903/error-creating-an-on-premise-multi-machine-service-fabric-cluster)

Comment: I copied your json file and added 2 more nodes to it; successfully created my cluster. Thanks.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Azure Service Fabric V5.1.156.9590 now includes ClusterConfig.Unsecure.MultiMachine.json which is the same as @Henrik's supplied json