# Error creating an on-premise multi-machine Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In order to test and evaluate SF for production use, I created one (single-machine) test cluster on a production machine with three nodes, which worked fine. However, I failed to create a multi-machine cluster with three nodes.

I followed these instructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/

All machines:

- are on the same (secure) network with the following IPs: 10.0.10.12, 10.0.11.12, 10.0.12.12.
- are virtual and were created freshly from the same image.
- are not part of a domain. The setup is done with the administrator account with the same password on all machines.
- using Windows Server 2012 R2 with PowerShell 4.0.
- have disabled firewalls (public and private).

This is the clusterConfig.json:

```
{
   "name":"SampleCluster",
   "clusterManifestVersion":"1.0.0",
   "apiVersion":"2015-01-01-alpha",
   "nodes":[
      {
         "nodeName":"vm1",
         "iPAddress":"10.0.10.12",
         "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
         "faultDomain":"fd:/dc1/fd1",
         "upgradeDomain":"UD0"
      },
      {
         "nodeName":"vm2",
         "iPAddress":"10.0.11.12",
         "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
         "faultDomain":"fd:/dc1/fd2",
         "upgradeDomain":"UD1"
      },
      {
         "nodeName":"vm3",
         "iPAddress":"10.0.12.12",
         "nodeTypeRef":"NodeType0",
         "faultDomain":"fd:/dc1/fd3",
         "upgradeDomain":"UD2"
      }
   ],
   "diagnosticsFileShare": {
        "etlReadIntervalInMinutes": "5",
        "uploadIntervalInMinutes": "10",
        "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "7",
        "etwStoreConnectionString": "file:c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\FileshareETW",
        "crashDumpConnectionString": "file:c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\FileshareCrashDump",
        "perfCtrConnectionString": "file:c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\FilesharePerfCtr"
    },
   "properties":{
       "reliabilityLevel": "Bronze",
      "nodeTypes": [
          {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpoint": "19001",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20001",
                "endPort": "20031"
            },
            "ephemeralPorts": {
                "startPort": "20032",
                "endPort": "20062"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
          }
      ],
      "fabricSettings": [
        {
          "name": "Setup",
          "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "FabricDataRoot",
                "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF"
            },
            {
                "name": "FabricLogRoot",
                "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF\\Log"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

When I start the cluster setup from one of the machines (it was 10.0.10.12), this is written to the PowerShell console:

```
Cab extracted.
Creating Service Fabric Cluster...
If it's taking too long, please check in Task Manager details and see if Fabric.exe for each node is running. If not, p
lease look at: 1. traces in DeploymentTraces directory and 2. traces in FabricLogRoot configured in ClusterConfig.json.
Trace folder doesn't exist. Creating trace folder: C:\copy\DeploymentTraces
Verifying remote procedure call access against cluster machines.
Processing and validating cluster config.
Creating FabricSettingsMetadata from C:\copy\ServiceFabricPackage\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\Configurations.csv
Configuring nodes.
Copying installer & package to all machines.
Configuring machine 10.0.10.12
Configuring machine 10.0.11.12
```

Here the setup remains for a few minutes. Then a timeout occurs:

```
Timed out waiting for Installer Service to start for machine 10.0.11.12.
CreateCluster Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service FabricInstallerSvc on computer '10.0.11.12'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.StartAndValidateInstallerServiceCompletion(String machineName, ServiceController i
nstallerSvc)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
Errors occurred during cluster creation.
CreateCluster Exception 0: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException
: Cannot start service FabricInstallerSvc on computer '10.0.11.12'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The syste
m cannot find the file specified
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.StartAndValidateInstallerServiceCompletion(String machineName, ServiceController i
nstallerSvc)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service FabricInstallerSvc on computer '10.0.11
.12'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.StartAndValidateInstallerServiceCompletion(String machineName, ServiceController i
nstallerSvc)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()<---
```

When I check the Services on the particular machine (10.0.11.12), I found the **Service Fabric Installer Service** in the list, but which is not running. Further I can find an error in the Windows Event Log showing this (which is in line with the error message above):

```
The Service Fabric Installer Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On the particular machine, I located the following log file: C:\ProgramData\SF\Log\traces\FabricInstallerService_5.1.150.9590_131111077992093094.trace. It contains this:

```
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Info    ,708,General.FabricInstallerServiceImpl,FabricInstallerService starting ...
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480bcf0,Attempting to attach child AsyncOperation 3b4480bdf0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480bdf0,Calling OnStart
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480bdf0,Attempting to attach child AsyncOperation 3b4480c9b0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c9b0,Calling OnStart
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c9b0,FinishComplete called with S_OK
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b44811270,Attempting to attach child AsyncOperation 3b44811630.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b44811630,Calling OnStart
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480bdf0,FinishComplete called with S_OK
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.FabricInstallerServiceImpl,FabricUpgradeManager open returned S_OK
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480bcf0,Detaching child AsyncOperation 3b4480bdf0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480bdf0,Detaching child AsyncOperation 3b4480c9b0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Info    ,1652,FabricInstallerService.FabricUpgradeManager,Upgrade started with FabricDataRoot:C:\ProgramData\SF, FabricLogRoot:C:\ProgramData\SF\Log, FabricCodePath:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code, FabricRoot:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric, TargetInformationFilePath:C:\ProgramData\SF\TargetInformation.xml, TargetInformationDescription:TargetInformationFileDescription { CurrentInstallation = WindowsFabricDeploymentDescription { IsValid = true, InstanceId = 0, MSILocation = , ClusterManifestLocation = , InfrastructureManifestLocation = , NodeName = , UpgradeEntryPointExe = , UpgradeEntryPointExeParameters = , UndoUpgradeEntryPointExe = FabricSetup.exe, UndoUpgradeEntryPointExeParameters = /operation:Uninstall , }TargetInstallation = WindowsFabricDeploymentDescription { IsValid = false, InstanceId = , MSILocation = , ClusterManifestLocation = , InfrastructureManifestLocation = , NodeName = , UpgradeEntryPointExe = , UpgradeEntryPointExeParameters = , UndoUpgradeEntryPointExe = , UndoUpgradeEntryPointExeParameters = , }}
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Info    ,1652,FabricInstallerService.FabricUpgradeManager,Stopping fabric host
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Info    ,1652,FabricInstallerService.FabricUpgradeManager,Error 0x80070424 while waiting for fabric host service to stop.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Error   ,1652,FabricInstallerService.FabricUpgradeManager,Unable to stop fabric host service; error 
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Error   ,1652,FabricInstallerService.FabricUpgradeManager,Error E_FAIL while trying to stop fabric host service
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Noise   ,1652,General.AsyncOperation@3b44811630,FinishComplete called with E_FAIL
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Warning ,1652,FabricInstallerService.FabricUpgradeManager,Upgrade finished with error E_FAIL
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Info    ,1636,General.FabricInstallerServiceImpl,service stopping (shutdown = false) ...
2016-06-22 22:23:19.224,Info    ,1636,General.FabricInstallerServiceImpl,Stop FabricUpgradeManager called
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Info    ,2472,General.FabricInstallerServiceImpl,Close FabricUpgradeManager, with timeout 5:00.000 
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480be00,Attempting to attach child AsyncOperation 3b4480c4d0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c4d0,Calling OnStart
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c4d0,Attempting to attach child AsyncOperation 3b4480c5d0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c5d0,Calling OnStart
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c5d0,FinishComplete called with S_OK
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c4d0,FinishComplete called with S_OK
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.FabricInstallerServiceImpl,Close FabricUpgradeManager returned S_OK
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480be00,Detaching child AsyncOperation 3b4480c4d0.
2016-06-22 22:23:19.240,Noise   ,2472,General.AsyncOperation@3b4480c4d0,Detaching child AsyncOperation 3b4480c5d0.
```

This is the point where I am stuck. My thoughts are:

- Communication and accessibility between the machines seem to be OK, since the setup files were copied, and the setup process started.
- The Service Fabric Installer Service seem to play an important role here.
- It seems that the Service Fabric Installer Service works properly on the machine where I started the setup process, but on the remote machines they fail.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  We have a similar issue at work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of your scenario as I've only had experience installing cluster using Windows Machine group or gMSA account - and it's always been a rather painful experience...but if you persist, you'll get there in the end!

You mention that it is running in a secured network, but not part of a domain? Typically in Active directory environments, SF runs under `NETWORK SERVICE` account - so potentially you can try adding all the machines to local Administrators group of each machine.

I know that with gMSA account, I had to add this to local admin group on each machine - as well as grant it logon as a service.

Other than that, I also suggest you check the event log - Administrators and Security Audit logs, in particular

Answer (score -2):

I hit the similar issue. Turns out that having Service Fabric SDK/Service Fabric  installed via the web installer was breaking my install. I uninstalled those and it worked.

Also i have issues running the script of a machine that wasn't going to be a node in the cluster. (I'd drop a comment but I don't have enough points)

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you resolved this?